# Mysql insert column from another table

Tags: mysql

Ok i want to copy column with records from one table to another from diffrent databases, I have same structure its only translation OF countries names. Whats the best way to do that, i try to dump sql file   only with colums and then write query but it seems it not posible?

```
INSERT INTO wp_drzava (NazivRo)
SELECT NazivRo FROM drzava
WHERE drzava.ID = wp_drzava.ID
```

I try something like this

Comment: and what's the problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use UPDATE instead.

`UPDATE wp_drzava 
JOIN drzava ON wp_drzava.ID = drzava.ID
SET wp_drzava.NazivRo = drzava.NazivRo`